# Aptitude wants to remove tons of packages

Tags: aptitude

I've used the search engine but do not manage to find a simple answer to this simple question:

How to avoid aptitude wanting to deinstall tons of packages when a simple upgrade of a single package would suffice?

Comment: Use `apt-get` instead? :-)

Comment: Can you give more details on your problem?. Which packages? Which dependencies?

Comment: It is not about specific dependencies. It is about general aptitude resolver behaviour. It always wants to remove instead of upgrading.

Comment: @Envite Maybe this is the behavior on your system but this is not always the case. If you want an anwser you must provide more details.

Comment: -1 | For you have not included any version (text or visual) of the command you have used and the result.

Comment: Problem is simple and general, not specific to any particular package or dependency, or combination of. It just happens that trying to upgrade packages with aptitude fires this issue: aptitude's resolver always prefers to remove packages instead of upgrading dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when aptitude wants to remove a lot of packages is because they are not marked as `manual` but `automatic` (indicated with an `A`).

Automatic packages get autoremoved when they are no longer needed.

You can mark the ones you want to to keep as manual to prevent this. In the menu: `package` > `mark manual`.